# Href in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been scouring the Interwebz, and I can't seem to find the answer.  How to I add href within my carousel links?  I tried to put the a tag outside of my h1 tag, but it destroys the functionality of the slider itself.

Here's my code?

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div id="my-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- indicators dot nov -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/Internet.jpg"  alt="Internet Services" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1 href="/Internet">Truespeed Internet Services</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/HomePhone.jpg" alt="Truespeed Internet Services" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Phone</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls or next and prev buttons -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have a fiddle?

Comment: Just add `href="link here"` to your `img` tags. Refer this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339638/how-do-i-add-a-links-to-pictures-in-twitter-bootstrap-carousel

Comment: @Pugazh THANK YOU SO MUCH!  I don't know how I didn't find that link... can you answer this so I can choose it?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just add the desired link to the `img` using `href` attribute. Check updated code below

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div id="my-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- indicators dot nov -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/Internet.jpg" href="http://google.com" alt="Internet Services" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1 href="/Internet">Truespeed Internet Services</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/HomePhone.jpg" href="http://google.com" alt="Truespeed Internet Services" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Phone</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls or next and prev buttons -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless there's been a major change that I've missed, href doesn't belong on an img tag.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bootply.com/nZjger87Zc#

You can add the `a` tags just outside the `H1` tags.