# I cannot link images to pages on my host in my carousel with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am trying to link images in my carousel to pages on my website.  I have looked at other answers here ([Href in Bootstrap Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030566/href-in-bootstrap-carousel))  I added the href where needed and I have the correct .js from the bootstrap site.  The link is on the same host as the page so it should be at least giving me the option to click it and go to the wrong page (404), but it isn't even acting like it is linked at all, with no option to even click on it.  I also tried the link to the webpage itself http://mywebsite.com/pageiwant.  I am very new at this, I have only been using HTML for a short amount of time.  What could I be doing wrong?  I am using Bootstrap 4.  Thank you in advance!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">  
   
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-centered align-right">

          <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide my-4" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/peridotandprehnite900x350.jpg" href="peridotandprehnite.html" alt="First slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/sterlingsilverdaisychain900x350.jpg" href="sterlingsilverchainwithdaisies.html" alt="Second slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/copperowl900x350.jpg" href="copperowlontwostrandcopperchain.html" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          
    <footer class="py-2 bg-color:#7EC1BD fixed-bottom">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Meow Meow Meow</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Holy moly sweet bajeezus!  I figured it out using [How do I add a links to pictures in Twitter Bootstrap Carousel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339638/how-do-i-add-a-links-to-pictures-in-twitter-bootstrap-carousel).  By wrapping each image into the href it is now working flawlessly!

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
      </head>
      <body>

    <div class="container">  
       
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-centered align-right">

              <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide my-4" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
<a href="peridotandprehnite.html">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/peridotandprehnite900x350.jpg" alt="First slide">
</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
<a href="sterlingilverdaisychain.html">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/sterlingsilverdaisychain900x350.jpg" alt="Second slide">
</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
<a href="copperowlontwostrancopperchain.html">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/copperowl900x350.jpg" alt="Third slide">
</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div>
              
        <footer class="py-2 bg-color:#7EC1BD fixed-bottom">
          <div class="container">
            <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Meow Meow Meow</p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.container -->
        </footer>

    </body>
    </html>
```