# Bootstrap Carousel to have different URL for each slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap carousel is located here: `testdomain.org/about.html` and when the slide changes, the URL in the address bar remains the same. I want the URL to auto change when the slides change to something like this:

```
https://testdomain.org/about.html#slide1
https://testdomain.org/about.html#slide2
https://testdomain.org/about.html#slide3
```

How can we make this happen?I created this [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/99ndj8hq/) for your convenience. I don't know how to go about writing JS for this :(

It's the standard bootstrap HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania">
      <div class="">
        <h3>Chania</h3>
        <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania">
      <div class="">
        <h3>Chania</h3>
        <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower">
      <div class="">
        <h3>Flowers</h3>
        <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower">
      <div class="">
        <h3>Flowers</h3>
        <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

DEMO Screenshot of the URL in the Address bar should look like this
[image]

Comment: You need to give an ID to each slide, and check `location.hash` on load and the `hashchange` event.

Comment: This has already been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339638/how-do-i-add-a-links-to-pictures-in-twitter-bootstrap-carousel. Wrap each image in a link.

Comment: @gcampbell Could you give a working demo?

Comment: @NathanielFlick: That's not what I want. I want the URL in the Address Bar of the browser to change when the slide changes. Not add a link to the slides.

Comment: @NathanielFlick I think that's slightly different.

Comment: No solution from anyone?! :(

Comment: So you want to be able to provide the #link and it goes to the page with the slide showing?

Comment: It's done. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Use the carousel Events to determine when a slide transition happens and which slide has been activated.  Then update the address bar and browser history with the slide URL.  Instructions for both are at the links below:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events

[Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)

Comment: I'm more of a html/css person. I'm no good at javascript and can't understand those tutorials. :(

Comment: Give it a try, you can do it!

Comment: I could possibly try if there's some working example. Anyways. thanks. Waiting for someone to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following javascript, amending references where applicable. You will also need to add an ID to `<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">`. I worked the below off the following - `<div class="carousel-inner" id="listbox" role="listbox">`.

```
childsList = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementById('listbox').children );

$("#myCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {
  window.location.hash = "slide" + (childsList.indexOf(event.relatedTarget) + 1);
}
```

This picks up the event of a slide changing, picks up the index of the slide and sets the '#' in the URL to '#slide[index of slide + 1]'. I hope this helps.

Here is a fiddle doing the same thing but outputting to a  rather than the URL. https://jsfiddle.net/JokerDan/22botkvm/